# How to add more Enum's to Spring Batch Status as well as configure special execution logic per new status

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Currently Spring Batch has a set of BatchStatus Enum's that represent the last status of a given job that. My question is consider that I would like to change the behaviour or include more status types due to my business logic. An example of one such status can be "MIGRATE", say upon status migrate occurring I have my logic migrate and perform some special operations.

How can I implement such behaviour in Spring Batch?

Thank you all for your suggestions.